# Span-style spacing with full width element

Tags: html, css, padding

The title is probably kind of confusing.

I have a list of some elements, that each have a CSS hover effect applied (the background lightens). However, I would like each element to fill all of the space in its container, which they currently don't do.

Ex:

[image: Elements not filling their space]

How it should be:

[image: See "Example 3"]

In addition, I need the elements to be close together, inline-element style, as seen in the first example. I have looked into `display:inline` and `display:inline-block` on a `div` tag; however, that caused the `div` to behave like in the first example (the element doesn't fill all of its horizontal space, visible from the hover effect). Ex:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">Example 1</div>
```

On the other hand, using a `span` has the inverse effect, causing a second-example-esque problem. Ex:

```
<span style="display:block">Example 1</span>
```

Is there any way to do **both**? i.e. Is there any type of element or CSS trick with inline-element-like vertical padding and block-element-like horizontal padding?

Comment: Can you show us a more complete example... html and css

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Why dont you just use a <li> list item and add a class and style the class? It looks like you are building a navigation?

Comment: In the first example, what you show us is not an "inline-element style", is a display: block style without margin and padding (except the 100% width). It's truly better to use an unordered list (ul and li elements with list-style-type: none) for your purpose, also from the semantic point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow something like the following:

**CSS:**

```
#nav{
    width: 33%;
    border: 2px dotted #000;
}
#nav ul{

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
   width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;

}
#nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #ffccaa;
}
#nav ul li a{
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/czungqu1/)

Comment: The OP asks about a list. In HTML lists are usually `ul` or `ol`. You can regard it as a suggestion to handle the requirement in more simple and modular way. @humble.rumble.6x3

Comment: "I have a list of some elements..."

Comment: This seems to solve my problem. For my purposes, it doesn't matter if I use a `span`, `div` or anything else, as long as the desired effect is achieved. The "unordered list" was the only suggestion that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 100%`

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4kmd65wL/))

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
```